# How do I set my unauthenticated page for my flask application?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-user

[Current unauthorized(?) page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhnnD.png)

Hi there! I am working on a project for capstone and my team and I have thrown everything at this problem, but we can't seem to figure it out. When users of our website request views that are protected by the @login_required or @roles_required() decorators when not logged in or not the right role, we are shown the page listed above. I have found the file 'flask_user/login.html' which seems to be the file displayed in the image above and yet whenever I make changes to this template's html directly, no changes are shown in the application. I have set the USER_UNAUTHENTICATED_ENDPOINT to 'login' and the USER_UNAUTHORIZED_ENDPOINT to 'login' as well in our config.py file, but to no avail. 'login' being the function name of our login view function. If I can provide more code/images/answer any questions I am more than willing. Please let me know what you all think is happening and if there is anything we should be doing differently. Thanks!

Comment: Yes please post some code for us to look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for not posting any code, it looks like my issue was using LoginManager at the same time as using UserManager, as well as using @login_required with @roles_required. I deleted LoginManager and @login_required and just used @roles_required and it worked for me. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Also I set USER_UNAUTHENTICATED_ENDPOINT to the right view function.